# How to change the size of bar in bar chart in shiny app?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, geom-bar

In my `shiny` app, I want to show the impact of user on a specific site (site 1 till site 10) compared to the impact on all sites.

[image]

The app is working fine. However I want to change the size of the bar. I couldn't change the bar size using `geom_bar(stat = "identity", size = 0.35)`

I want to change the bar size especially when I'm selecting `allsites` because the size becomes so wide

[image]

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

**Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

load("df.rdata")

ui <- fluidPage(
fluidRow(
  column(2,
         radioButtons(inputId = "site",
             label = "Select site",
             choiceNames = c("allsites", "site1", "site2", "site3", "site4", "site5", "site6", "site7", "site8", "site9", "site10"),
             choiceValues = c("allsites", "site1", "site2", "site3", "site4", "site5", "site6", "site7", "site8", "site9", "site10"),
             selected = "allsites")
),
column(10,
  fluidRow( 
  tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
              tabPanel("Bar chart", 
                       tags$br(),
                       tags$br(),
                       plotOutput("bar_chart", width = "75%")
              )
  )
  )
)
)
)


server <- function(input, output, session){

site <- reactive({
  input$site
})


output$bar_chart <- renderPlot({

  df1 <- df %>%
    dplyr::filter(site %in% c("allsites", site()))


  ggplot(df1, aes(site, median, fill = site))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", size = 0.35)+
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
                  width = .09, size=0.2)+
    facet_wrap(~site, ncol = 2, scales ="free")

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(site = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 3L), .Label = c("allsites", "site1", "site10", 
"site2", "site3", "site4", "site5", "site6", "site7", "site8", 
"site9"), class = "factor"), lower = c(40.97, 1.92, 7.5, 2.66, 
1.18, 0.72, 6.92, 6.87, 3.41, 2.17, 4.2), median = c(43.18, 2.56, 
8.87, 3.17, 1.84, 1.04, 8.14, 8.1, 4.96, 3.03, 5.87), upper = c(45.54, 
3.64, 10.59, 3.75, 2.63, 1.65, 9.49, 9.45, 6.18, 4.04, 8.15)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `width` instead of `size` in the `geom_bar` function.

[image]

**Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(site = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
                                        9L, 10L, 11L, 3L), .Label = c("allsites", "site1", "site10", 
                                                                      "site2", "site3", "site4", "site5", "site6", "site7", "site8", 
                                                                      "site9"), class = "factor"), lower = c(40.97, 1.92, 7.5, 2.66, 
                                                                                                             1.18, 0.72, 6.92, 6.87, 3.41, 2.17, 4.2), median = c(43.18, 2.56, 
                                                                                                                                                                  8.87, 3.17, 1.84, 1.04, 8.14, 8.1, 4.96, 3.03, 5.87), upper = c(45.54, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  3.64, 10.59, 3.75, 2.63, 1.65, 9.49, 9.45, 6.18, 4.04, 8.15)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     -11L))




ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(2,
           radioButtons(inputId = "site",
                        label = "Select site",
                        choiceNames = c("allsites", "site1", "site2", "site3", "site4", "site5", "site6", "site7", "site8", "site9", "site10"),
                        choiceValues = c("allsites", "site1", "site2", "site3", "site4", "site5", "site6", "site7", "site8", "site9", "site10"),
                        selected = "allsites")
    ),
    column(10,
           fluidRow( 
             tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                         tabPanel("Bar chart", 
                                  tags$br(),
                                  tags$br(),
                                  plotOutput("bar_chart", width = "75%")
                         )
             )
           )
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session){

  site <- reactive({
    input$site
  })


  output$bar_chart <- renderPlot({

    df1 <- df %>%
      dplyr::filter(site %in% c("allsites", site()))


    ggplot(df1, aes(site, median, fill = site))+
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.35)+
      geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper),
                    width = .09, size=0.2)+
      facet_wrap(~site, ncol = 2, scales ="free")

  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```